# Share Video Preview Image using ACTION_SEND with Android Sharesheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-sharesheet

Since Android 10+, the Android Sharesheet has supported providing image previews of files shared using `ACTION_SEND`.
Making a custom `ActivityResultContract` with the [Android documentation for sending binary content](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content),
you get something like this:

```kotlin
class ShareVideo : ActivityResultContract<Uri, Unit>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Uri): Intent {
        return Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            type = "video/*"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, input)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
        return
    }
}

...
@Composable
fun ShareVideo(file: Uri) {
    val shareVideo = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ShareVideo()) {}

    Button(onClick={ shareVideo.launch(file) }) {
       Text("Share Video")
    }
}
```

However, this does not result in a preview image in the Sharesheet.
What am I doing wrong?
[image: Sharesheet without preview]

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, every answer implementing `ACTION_SEND` wraps the `Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)` with `Intent.createChooser(...)`

That is, every `ACTION_SEND` intent should be wrapped inside of an `ACTION_CHOOSER` intent, which itself mostly copies the information found in the `ACTION_SEND` intent, which makes you wonder what the difference is.
[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CHOOSER), the `ACTION_CHOOSER` intent has a richer interface for when defaults are not allowed, or don't make sense. The `ACTION_SEND` intent is a simpler interface for when a default *is* intended.

So the correct `ActivityResultContract` implementation for sharing binary files with `ACTION_SEND` is something like

```kotlin
class ShareVideo : ActivityResultContract<Uri, Unit>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Uri): Intent {
        return Intent.createChooser(Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            type = "video/*"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, input)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }, null)
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
        return
    }
}
```

[image: Sharesheet with an image preview]